# Angular2 not loading in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, angular

i have created cordova app which is running fine in browser while deploy the same in android mobile its not running. I am using angular 2 in this app. When i did the remote debugging I saw the following error in console.

> **Failed to load file:///android_asset/www/lib/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic//bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

[image: Error]

Then i check the source tab in developer tool the angular lib folder is not shown there.

[image: Error]

when i check the same while running in browser the angular files shown in source tab

[image: Error]

What may cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the issue. in the JS reference i have one extra slash that cause the problem

file:///android_asset/www/lib/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`//bundles/`platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js

After removing the extra slash now working in mobile

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I don't see where I can remove the extra slash.

Comment: it's in your systemjs.config.js. but now that quick start example was updated,in case if you are using old version you need update following line in systemjs.config.js.  
function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }